# Socket.IO connect working only if run code from Node repl

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

The client does not connect to the server if the code is run from a file, and **connects if you run the same code from the repl**.

Server code:

```
const http = require("http");
const express = require("express");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
const io = socketIO(server);
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    console.log("Wow! Client socket connected!");
});
server.listen(8081, "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log("Starting server on port 8081");
});
```

Client code (also node.js):

```
const socketIOClient = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = socketIOClient("http://0.0.0.0:8081");
while (true);
```

Here is the trace of the created Socket object. The first is when try run node client. The readyState becomes opening, connected false and disconnected true.

```
Socket {
  io:
   Manager {
     nsps: { '/': [Circular] },
     subs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     opts:
      { reconnect: true,
        path: '/socket.io',
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        secure: false,
        port: '8081' },
     _reconnection: true,
     _reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
     _reconnectionDelay: 1000,
     _reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
     _randomizationFactor: 0.5,
     backoff: Backoff { ms: 1000, max: 5000, factor: 2, jitter: 0.5, attempts: 0 },
     _timeout: 20000,
     readyState: 'opening',
     uri: 'http://0.0.0.0:8081',
     connecting: [ [Circular] ],
     lastPing: null,
     encoding: false,
     packetBuffer: [],
     encoder: Encoder {},
     decoder: Decoder { reconstructor: null },
     autoConnect: true,
     engine:
      Socket {
        secure: false,
        agent: false,
        hostname: '0.0.0.0',
        port: '8081',
        query: {},
        upgrade: true,
        path: '/socket.io/',
        forceJSONP: false,
        jsonp: true,
        forceBase64: false,
        enablesXDR: false,
        timestampParam: 't',
        timestampRequests: undefined,
        transports: [Array],
        transportOptions: {},
        readyState: 'opening',
        writeBuffer: [],
        prevBufferLen: 0,
        policyPort: 843,
        rememberUpgrade: false,
        binaryType: null,
        onlyBinaryUpgrades: undefined,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        pfx: null,
        key: null,
        passphrase: null,
        cert: null,
        ca: null,
        ciphers: null,
        rejectUnauthorized: true,
        forceNode: false,
        id: null,
        upgrades: null,
        pingInterval: null,
        pingTimeout: null,
        pingIntervalTimer: null,
        pingTimeoutTimer: null,
        transport: [XHR],
        _callbacks: [Object] },
     skipReconnect: false,
     _callbacks: { '$open': [Array], '$packet': [Array], '$close': [Array] } },
  nsp: '/',
  json: [Circular],
  ids: 0,
  acks: {},
  receiveBuffer: [],
  sendBuffer: [],
  connected: false,
  disconnected: true,
  flags: {},
  subs:
   [ { destroy: [Function: destroy] },
     { destroy: [Function: destroy] },
     { destroy: [Function: destroy] } ],
  _callbacks:
   { '$connecting': [ [Function: onConnecting] ],
     '$connect': [ [Function] ] } }
```

I tried different SocketIO version, different OS, various of optional params but nothing helped.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to local host ? (I assume you are trying to connect within the same host : const socket = socketIOClient("http://127.0.0.1:8081");
Are you behind a proxy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

This is because of my infinite loop and poor understanding of the js runtime ...

I thought the script should complete when the execution reached the end of the file, and wrote a loop to prevent this, but it seems instead I blocked the JS event loop.

:X